# How to make a formula in a MATLAB figure on the y-axis bold along with LaTeX interpreter?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a formula in y-axis bold along with LaTeX interpreter. I've tried this but it is not bold,

```
ylabel('Detector $(i)$', 'FontWeight','bold', 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ylabel('\boldmath \bf{Detector$(i)$}', 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

Comment: That worked :) Also how can I do the same thing with the yticks (they are LaTeX as well)? I've tried this,
set(gca,'FontWeight','bold','fontsize',12);
but it just makes them larger not bold.

Comment: I think the FontWeight option doesn't work with LaTeX tick labels. You could try directly modifying the content of the labels to use `\bf{some number}`. You can access the tick labels by doing `ax = gca;  ax.YTickLabel`.

Comment: Thanks. How about the colorbar ticks?

Comment: `c = colorbar; c.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex'; c.TickLabels`

Comment: it just makes the ticks LaTeX. How about making them bold as well?

Comment: Same as before, you have to edit the content of each cell in `c.TickLabels`. For example if the 2nd tick value is 0.1, you should do `c.TickLabels{2} = '\bf{0.1}'`.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way to make them all bold?

Comment: If you are okay with regular text, you could do `c.TickLabelInterpreter = 'tex'; c.FontWeight = 'bold'`. But for latex, I don't know of any other way unfortunately.